# Wine Office 2007 launch problem

Tags: wine

I am new to Wine and I have this error while opening POWERPNT.EXE:

```
0009:err:eventlog:ReportEventW L"Microsoft Office PowerPoint"
0009:err:eventlog:ReportEventW L"PowerPoint failed to start correctly last time.  Starting PowerPoint in safe mode will help you correct or isolate a startup problem in order to successfully start the program.  Some functionality may be disabled in this mode.\n\nDo you want to start PowerPoint in safe mode?"
0009:err:mscoree:CLRRuntimeInfo_GetRuntimeDirectory error reading registry key for installroot
```

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: nah m8 diffrent problem there

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using PowerPoint,I recommend you to use Apache OpenOffice as it is available for Ubuntu and provides same features.

Comment: i don't know how to use it tho

Comment: Installing OpenOffice is a struggle - why not just use LibreOffice?

Comment: my distro already came with it :D

Comment: installing OpenOffice is not a struggle,if you want i will tell you the steps for installation.